# Forward lighting and bump effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why bump effect do not work with forward lighting?

> Player settings > Other settings > Rendering path = "Forward"

I using Unity 5.

Comment: How is the bump effect done normally? Multi-pass shaders often have problems in forward rendering.

Comment: i think its better if you provide more details. maybe you can show your shader code.